# Android Retrofit always returns false value for the type boolean while fetching jsonobject

Tags: android, boolean, retrofit, json

I am new using retrofit and here i am stuck with an problem where retrofit always returns false for boolean type object which is actually 1(true) which i am retriving.

here below is my pojo class for retriving data

```
public class JobsModel implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("posted_on")
private String postedOn;
@SerializedName("is_active")
private boolean isActive=false;

public JobsModel(String postedOn, boolean isActive) {
    this.postedOn=postedOn;
    this.isActive=isActive;
}

public Boolean getPostedOn() {
    return postedOn
}

public void setPostedOn(String postedOn) {
    postedOn= postedOn
}

public Boolean getActive() {
    return isActive;
}

public void setActive(Boolean active) {
    isActive = active;
}
```

}

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Most probably, your @SerializedName("is_active") is wrong. Please check this line.

Answer (score 2):

first of all change private `boolean isActive=false;` to `private boolean Active;`

Secondly change

```
   public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        isActive = active;   }
```

to

```
public void setActive(boolean active) {
    Active = active;

}
```

and If your JSON contains any object starting with I then change it,cause it will always return false.
Hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to be sure that `@SerializedName("is_active")` is correct and matching your json name.

Also you do not need to init value like:

```
private boolean isActive=false;
```

I modified your getter and setter. Can you try with this:

```
public boolean getActive() {
    return isActive;
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
    isActive = active;
}
```

If you're using Retrofit 2.0 there's a strange behavior (i think it's a bug) about parsing `boolean`.

When we try to parse `boolean` json object which's name starts with `"I"` it always returns false. This is not relevant to you but maybe there's a problem like this. If you can, you can try to use a different json name for your object.

Comment: so what can we try for the value boolean

Comment: i refactored your code. try to replace your code which i give in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean is primitive type in Java an it's default value is false
If your json is_active value hasn't any value then is_active by default be false!
For avoiding this problem use Boolean not boolean type!

Answer (score -1):

You already initialised this as false. Do this

```
private boolean isActive;
```